# vuejs маршрутизайия с относительными переходами

Tags: vue.js, маршрутизация

Всем привет,

Имея в routes/web.php laravel 5.5/vuejs.25 приложения:

```
Route::get('tasks_listing', 'TasksController@listing')->name('tasks_listing');
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']])->middleware('WorkTextString');
```

В resources/assets/js/app.js определены список и редакторы задач(для создания и редакторования ):

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        components: {
            tasksIndex: TasksIndex,            
        }
    },
    ...
    {path: '/admin/tasks/create', component: TasksCreate, name: 'createTask'},
    {path: '/admin/tasks/edit/:id', component: TasksEdit, name: 'editTask'},
    ...


const router = new VueRouter( {
    // mode: 'hash', // default
    // mode: 'history',
    routes
})
```

В меню:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('admin.tasks_listing') }}">My tasks</a></li>
<li><router-link :to="{name: 'createTask'}" class="" >New task</router-link></li>
```

Ссылки нормально работают если открыть список задач а потом создать новый и сохранившись опять открыть список

Проблема если находясь скажем в профайле( по ссылке /admin/user_profile#/ ) и кликнуть на создания задачи с переходом на 
/admin/user_profile#/admin/tasks/create
и далее неправильном переходе при сохранении на /admin/user_profile#/

Почему относительные ссылки при переходе на создание задачи и как это исправить ?

Да и вобще если нужно перейти на другую страницу( например при провереке что нет доступа к странице)
со страницы http://local-tasks.com/admin/tasks_listing

```
this.$router.push({path: '/dashboardIndex'});
```

То урл октрывшейся страницы 
http://local-tasks.com/admin/tasks_listing#/dashboardIndex

Спасибо !

Answer (score 2):

У вас в коде закомментированна строка `mode: 'history'`. Если не ошибаюсь, то она отвечает за то, будет ли у вас отображаться хэш тэг в урле или нет.
Посмотрите тут https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html может это то, что вам сейчас нужно?